# Como usar el resultado de un select como un where de otro select posterior?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo toda la condición `WHERE` que necesito como un campo de otra tabla, y al traer ese valor con un `SELECT` adentro del `WHERE` da el error:

> "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ..."

Les paso el resultado del primer `SELECT` que trae el `WHERE` que necesito usar en la segunda consulta:

**1er. `SELECT`:**

```sql
SELECT SQL_FILTER_RULE FROM PROMOCION_GRUPO WHERE ID_PROMOCION = 16
```

con el resultado:

```sql
(STA11.PROMO_MENU <> 'P' AND (STA11.PERFIL IN ('A','V'))) AND (STA11.COD_STA11 IN ('0100200708','030006527'))
```

**2do. `SELECT`:**

```sql
SELECT STA11.COD_ARTICU
FROM STA11 
WHERE (SELECT SQL_FILTER_RULE FROM PROMOCION_GRUPO WHERE ID_PROMOCION = 16)
```

con el resultado de error:

> "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'".

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Es que sql no interpreta el contenido del select, espera un booleano... si queres hacer eso, tendrias que construir la clausula where, utilizando un procedimiento almacenado...

Comment: Lo que estás tratando de hacer es un gran problema de seguridad ya que abre la puerta a inyección de SQL.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puedes utilizar el SELECT en una condición de WHERE. Lo que se puede hacer es una función SQL almacenando la información del primer SELECT para luego utilizarlo en la consulta principal.

Los nombres en los DECLARE son solo ejemplos.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @WHERE = SQL_FILTER_RULE 
FROM PROMOCION_GRUPO 
WHERE ID_PROMOCION = 16;

SET @SQL = N'SELECT STA11.COD_ARTICU FROM STA11 WHERE ' + @WHERE;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Pero esto no le resuelve el problema.. el quiere que lo que esta en el campo SQL_FILTER_RULE  sea su where...

Comment: hola intenté hacer un procedimiento almacenado con las lineas que me pasaste Stefan pero no lo logro hacer, porque no distingo en cuál parte está definido el procedimiento almacenado y cómo después lo puedo insertar como WHERE en una seguna consulta SQL, si alguien me puede dar una ayuda más especifica lo agradería mucho !!!

Comment: gbianchi me intrepretó exactamente, necesito poder usar el resultado del primer SELECT directamente como WHERE del segundo SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo logré con el procedimiento almacenado. Paso el código para que le sirva a alguien más de la comunidad:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ArtisPromo]
AS

    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @WHERE = SQL_FILTER_RULE 
    FROM PROMOCION_GRUPO 
    WHERE ID_PROMOCION = 16;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT STA11.COD_ARTICU FROM STA11 WHERE ' + @WHERE;

    EXEC (@SQL);

    END
```